# Reading an OS X formatted iPod on Windows

Tags: ipod

Is it possible to read songs from an iPod, thats formatted for Mac (HFS+ formatted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be, if it's formated in FAT32.

Otherwise, you could try [HFSExplorer](http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/hfsx.html), which is open-sourced.

You also have a couple of commercial options like [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/) or [Transmac](http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm), which both have time-limited full-functioning demos.

Comment: I think "formatted for Mac" means it's using HFS, not FAT32.

Comment: Yep, thus the reason I expanded the answer to include HFS-reading software for windows

Comment: I do believe the answer i have given is both valid and works. Fat32 will work on both OS/X and Windows. It's fair to assume that the iPod MAY be formatted with Fat32, and the OP hasn't tried connecting it to windows? It most certainly is NOT worth a down-vote IMO

Comment: unless of-course the suggestions I have given absolutely will not work that is? A reason would be nice at least